# How to setup Debezium for Kafka running in Docker for MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, docker, apache-kafka, debezium

I am new to Debezium, Kafka, and Docker. I have successfully installed Docker and it is running on my locahost.

I am attempting to go through the Debezium tutorial at: https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/tutorial/README.md#debezium-tutorial

I went to the section for SQL Server: and the first step says to `# Start the topology as defined in https://debezium.io/docs/tutorial/`. I successfully ran through that tutorial. But, it is for MySQL and not MSSQL Server. Anyways, I went back to the `../debezium-tutorial` and the first line tells me to run:

```
export DEBEZIUM_VERSION=1.1
docker-compose -f docker-compose-sqlserver.yaml up
```

The tutorial does not discuss how to create the `docker-compose-sqlserver.yaml`. I checked Debezium's github site for this file and it is not there. Am I supposed to create this file manually or am I missing something in the steps?

In order to get Debezium to work, am I supposed to create and run a SQL Server instance in Docker, or can I use the instance that is running on my localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker Compose is included in the tutorials repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples.git
cd debezium-examples/tutorial
export DEBEZIUM_VERSION=1.1
docker-compose -f docker-compose-sqlserver.yaml up
```